# Copy elements from 3 lists to one in android

Tags: android

I have 3 lists:

```
List<PointF> points = forumlaOfFunctionCharts(series1Numbers);
List<PointF> points2 = forumlaOfFunctionCharts(series2Numbers);
List<PointF> points3 = forumlaOfFunctionCharts(series3Numbers);
```

How I can copy all elements from this 3 lists to one list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use the addAll method as follows:

```
points.addAll(points2);
points.addAll(points3);
```

And everything will be copied to your "points" list.

See reference [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

Answer (score 1):

i think you can Do it like this:

```
List<PointF> newList = new List<PointF>();
newList.addAll(points1);
newList.addAll(points2);
newList.addAll(points3);
```

but i don't Know what

```
forumlaOfFunctionCharts
```

is doing...

Comment: 2 comments here: It doesn't matter what forumlaOfFunctionCharts does, since it's inside of a list. Also why would you create a new list when you want to merge 3 lists?

Comment: thx for the fotmula.... Information. i created a list to have the original, splitted lists, too, maybe it's needed...